# Can I condition an specific js event in an if statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an edit in place function, which needs to save the new value when the element loses focus. The thing is these are elements in a table, so each one of them has the element id followed by the id they have in the database, and that's why I couldn't just use `$('#id').on('event', function(){}`.

The element looks something like this:

```
<td>
<div id="quant<?php echo $id_product; ?>" 
onclick="live_update('<?php echo $id_product; ?>')">

     <?php echo $quantity;?>

</div>
</td>
```

and the js looks something like this:

```
function live_update(id){
    
    var quantity = $('#quant'+id).text().trim();
    
    $('#quant'+id).html('');
    $('<input></input>')
        .attr({
            'type': 'text',
            'name': 'name_quant'+id,
            'id': 'id_quant'+id,
            'size': '5',
            'value': quantity,
            'minlength' : '1',
            'maxlength' : 4
        })
        .appendTo('#quant'+id);
    $('#id_quant'+id).focus();
}
```

So far so good, the thing is I now need to update that specific element when the newly generated input loses focus, so I need to pass not only it's html id, but it's database id too, so I can't just use `$('#id_quant').on('blur', function(){}` because it won't know which element in the table to listen.

So I figured I would call another function just like this one when the new input loses focus, but I'm not sure if I can do that, and I don't know how the syntax would be.
In my mind it looks like this:

```
if($('#id_quant'+id).blur){ function ajax_update(id) }
```

or

```
if($(blur('#id_quant'+id))){ function ajax_update(id) }
```

I'm not really sure I can do that though.

Answer (score 0):

Apply a class and a `data-id` attribute to your dynamic elements

```
function live_update(id){

    var quantity = $('#quant'+id).text().trim();

    $('#quant'+id).html('');
    $('<input></input>')
        .attr({
            'type': 'text',
            'name': 'name_quant'+id,
            'id': 'id_quant'+id,
            'size': '5',
            'value': quantity,
            'minlength' : '1',
            'maxlength' : 4,
            'data-id', id // here
        })
        .addClass('inline-editor') // and here
        .appendTo('#quant'+id);
    $('#id_quant'+id).focus();
}
```

Which (dynamically) for blur on these items, and read the id within - allowing you to make your ajax call

```
$(document).on('blur','.inline-editor', function(){
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    // make ajax call
    ajax_update(id);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying!. I have a problem though. The function stops working when I add `.addClass('inline-editor');`

Comment: Also, did you mean me to add that second function inside the first one? Or as a separate one?

Comment: @F_Bass for comment 1 you've added a semicolon that was not in my code - stops the call to `appendTo`. For comment 2: no, it should just be inside a document ready handler.

Comment: Sorry, i deleted the semicolon and it started working once again. Now i got the second part working but with a different fix though, something I had not seen when i first tried it. Thanks for your help!